# mysql - how to insert multiple records and delete remaining ones

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-performance

Lets start with an example. There's a table:

```
CREATE TABLE  X (
 id INT(32) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 account INT(32),
 value INT(32),
 primary KEY (id)
)
```

What I want to achieve is to ensure that given account has specified set of values (and only these values). Basically, how to do below efficiently:

```
delete from X where account = 5;
insert into X (account, value) values 
(5, 0), 
(5, 2), 
(5, 3)
...
(5, 99);
```

The caveat is that usually just one value changes (appears or disappears).
Pretty much I have a set of values which changes, but instead of receiving deltas I'm getting whole set I need to efficiently reflect the difference. There will not be more than 100 values for given account at any time and usually there will be just 2-3. The changes happen thousands times per second. Changes to the same account are rare (usually just several, but could be more occasionally).

What I thought about is to set id account*1000+sequence_id to increase data locality for rows with the same account. Also instead of delete+reinsert I can do (pseudocode):

```
$current_values = select value from X where account = 5;
$to_add = $new_values not in $current_values
$to_remove = $current_values not in $new_values
delete from X where value in $to_remove
insert into X (account, value) values (5, $to_add[0]), (5, $to_add[1])...
```

How can I do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `INDEX(account)` to X.
2. Collect the incoming information in a temporary table. `tmp`.
3. `DELETE X FROM X, ( SELECT DISTINCT account FROM tmp ) y WHERE x.account=y.account;` [Check the syntax, and test before going into production.]
4. `INSERT INTO X (account, value) SELECT (account, value) FROM tmp;`

If you are using InnoDB , then I recommend `BEGIN; DELETE...; INSERT...; COMMIT;`.  This will keep other connections from finding rows deleted that are about to be re-inserted.

If that is too slow; let's talk further.

An aside:  `INT(32)` -- the "(32)" means nothing.  An INT is a 4-byte integer regardless of the value after it.

Comment: I went with "easy" - select all records with given account id, calculate the different on the application side, issue multi-value queries (at most 3) - insert/update/delete. Most of the time just one row changes so it will be select + one query to store the change. Also the queries are pretty simple, nothing tricky for the optimizer. I'll see how it performs before considering more elaborate approaches. Thanks for the tip on INT(32).

Answer (score 0):

use a not exists thus leaving the existing records alone and onyl removing those you didn't provide in your list..

```
Delete from X t1 where not exists
(Select 1 from X t2 where t1.account=t2.account and t1.value=t2.value
and value in (0,2,3,...99))
```

now if you have a way of identifying 0,2,3...999 without having to pass it in, all the better as you may run into a limit using an in clause.

This is all contained in one statement making it less vulnerable to problems with multiple users playing with the same account.